# Java hashCode from multiple fields

Tags: java, oop, equals, hashcode

Given a class like so:

```
class MyObject {
  private String id1;
  private String id2;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof MyObject)) {
        return false;
    }
    MyObject other = (MyObject) o;
    return id1.equals(other.id1) || id2.equals(other.id2);
  }
}
```

Notice that equality does not depend on both fields matching, either field works. What would be a suitable `hashCode` implementation for this class?

Comment: I don't believe there is any hashcode that can be used for this.

Comment: @Andreas you could use the minimum of the two.

Comment: @AndyTurner No you can't. ["A", "B"] vs ["C", "B"] are equal, but lowest hash code is not.

Comment: @Andreas Hm, right. Well, you can use a constant...

Comment: @Andreas but surely this definition of equality violates the general contract of equals (specifically, transitivity).

Comment: @AndyTurner True, but a constant is not much of a hash code. It would work, but basically turns a `HashMap` into a `LinkedList`

Comment: @AndyTurner Agreed. It violates the contract of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a valid implementation of `equals`.

Specifically, it violates the transitivity requirement.

As such, you can't implement `hashCode` "correctly" either, aside from making all instances have the same hash code.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: I've extended HashSet<String> and implemented `add` and `contains` to work for this. Does that sound like the right move here?

Comment: @mkohram extending HashSet *never* sounds like the right thing to do, especially if you are changing the behaviour of existing methods.

Comment: How else would you de-duplicate a list of these objects?

Comment: Also I'm not changing behaviour. Just added a `add(MyObject o)` and `contains(MyObject o)` to `HashSet<String>`.

Comment: That still sounds like it won't work.  Instead, make e.g. a `Map<String, MyObject> mapFromId1` and a `Map<String, MyObject> mapFromId2` and check both of them for each new object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's basically what the implementations of my `add` and `contains` look like. It's just abstracted away so every time I want to "add" MyObject to the set I don't have to do 2 inserts. Thanks.

Comment: You _shouldn't_ do that abstraction, not in a thing that's pretending to be a `HashSet` or a `Set` at all.  `Set`s should only reflect `equals` behavior, and _correct_, contract-satisfying `equals` behavior at that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I see what you are saying. So every time I want to check `contains` in the `Map` you talked about I would do 2 (or more) checks in the code? That is a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Or create your own class that does these operations for you but doesn't pretend to be a Set.

Comment: Thanks that is what I will do.